# How to create an ASP.NET custom control with a dash in the name?

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

I want to set up an ASP.NET custom control such that it has a custom name, specifically, with a hyphen within it, so it might look like this in markup:

```
<rp:do-something runat="server" id="doSomething1" />
```

I don't mind if this syntax requires setting up a tag mapping in web.config or something to that effect, but the [tagMapping element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164641.aspx) doesn't quite match up for what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't think this is possible due to the restrictions on class namings.  I don't believe you can refer to a control class in markup without refering to it by name

Is there a specific reason you need the hyphen?

Answer (score 1):

John, you're right.  I did some searching in Reflector and it looks like it doesn't get there:

```
Type ITagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(string tagName, IDictionary attribs)
{
    string str;
    string str2 = this._nsRegisterEntry.Namespace;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str2))
    {
        str = tagName;
    }
    else
    {
        str = str2 + "." + tagName;
    }
    if (this._assembly != null)
    {
        Type type = null;
        try
        {
            type = this._assembly.GetType(str, true, true);
        }
```

Implemented in System.Web.UI.NamespaceTagNameToTypeMapper, System.Web.

@Jonathan: I have a specific business reason for wanting to do it this way.  Oh well.